# Change HTML Textbox layout

Tags: html, css

Hi i would like to know how to change the text box in HTML to just a line rather than a box because i am trying to make a webpage look like  a PDF form and for a neat outlook i would like to change the text box design to just a long line so the user can type his name or whatever the field requires him to do..

Comment: You can do this with just CSS, you don't need javascript.

Comment: Style it with CSS. Beware though that altering the look of form inputs too drastically can severely break user expectations.

Comment: @JamesBlack - I think the OP has an `<input type="text" />` element. I initially thought it was a `<textarea>` also, but I don't think so.

Comment: to clarify, what you're looking for is an input that looks something like  NAME:______________, correct?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want a more specific selector, but this should make a reasonable starting point:

```
input { 
    border-style: none;
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}
```

Comment: not sure how to do this but i found this useful tks so much for a start

Answer (score 0):

You mean to display a `<textarea>` as an `<input type="text">`?

In html, i assume, via `<textarea cols="" rows="1">` or via CSS styling the `width` and `height` of the element

Answer (score 0):

For single lines of input, I'd use a `<input type="text" />`, which actually is the default `type` and can be abbreviated to just `<input />` (I'm assuming xhtml in these examples).

Comment: not xhtml but this did the trick...<textarea style="border: 0px solid #000000;">blah</textarea>